# MS SQL return Null

Tags: android, sql, sql-server

here i am trying to connect my android app to ms sql server but unfortunately, i am always getting null

```
         Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();                 
         DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.43.40:49172/info;user=" + username + ";password=" + password);

        String username = "sa";
        String password = "mypc107";

        String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.43.185 :49172;instance=SQLE2008;databaseName=app;user=sa;password=mypc107";

        Connection DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, username, password);

        Log.w("Connection","open");

        Log.w("Connection","open");
        Statement stmt = DbConn.createStatement();
        ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from info ");


        EditText num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        num.setText(reset.getString(1));

        DbConn.close();
```

Comment: You need to call `reset.next()` to advance the cursor to the first record in the result set.

Comment: Consider scrubbing out specific connection string details when you post your code online. While they may be internal-access only, don't give even a chance. Especially that SA account...

Comment: I am getting error here 
        Connection DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, username, password);